# SQL for getting products created on particular day

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get the product created five days before. From start of fifth day to end of fifth day. I have shown my table structure. 
[image]

What will be SQL query for getting for products created exactly before five days.

Comment: timestamp column's data type?

Comment: timestamp doesn't look like a `datetime` datatype, it doesn't even look like a date. If it is only time, how do you expect to extract a `day` from it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are storing [**`UNIX TIME`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

To get the records of 5th day backward from current date:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM your_table
WHERE `timestamp` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
AND `timestamp` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE(timestamp) = '2016-06-08'
```